# Angular.js ng-trasclude not picking up transcluded content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple ng-transclude in my directive; however, the transcluded content is not being picked up. Is there anything wrong in the following code?

Directive:

```
app.directive('modal', function($document){
return{
  templateUrl: "../templates/modal.html",
  restrict: "E",
  scope:{
      modalOpen: '=open',
      options: '=',
      onClose: '&'
    },
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: '../templates/modal.html',
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.close = function(){
        $scope.modalOpen = false;
        $scope.onClose();
      }
    },
    link: function($scope, el){

  var options = angular.extend({
    height: '250px',
    width: '500px',
    top: '20%',
    left: '30%'
  }, $scope.options);

  el.find('.modal-container').css({
    'left': options.left,
    'top': options.top,
    'height': options.height + 'px',
    'width': options.width + 'px'
  })

  var pageHeight = $document.height();
  var pageWidth = $document.width();
    el.find('modal-blackout').css({
      'width': pageWidth + 'px',
      'height': pageHeight + 'px'
    })
}
}            
});
```

templateURL:

```
<div class="modal-blackout" ng-show="modalOpen">
<div class="modal-container">
    <a class="modal-close" ng-click="close()">X</a>
      <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
  </div>
</div>
```

View:

```
<modal open="modalOpen" options="{top:35, height:300}" on-close="modalClosed(response)">
     <div ng-controller="modalCtrl">
      <h1>Body</h1>
        <div class="" ng-click="close('yes')">Yes</div>
        <div class="" ng-click="close('no')">No</div>
    </div>
  </modal>
```

Rendered html:

```
<modal open="modalOpen" options="{top:35, height:300}" on-close="modalClosed(response)" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
  <div class="modal-blackout" ng-show="modalOpen">
    <div class="modal-container" style="left: 30%; top: 35px; height: 300px;">
     <a class="modal-close" ng-click="close()">close</a>
      <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
  </div>
</div>
</modal>
```

Why is `<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>` not picking up the transcluded content?

Comment: What do you mean by "not picking up"? Is it not rendered?

Comment: no it's just returning <ng-transclude></ng-transclude> instead of rendering the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directive has an error, which is probably why it doesn't render anything.

Instead of using `$document.height()` - it should be `$document.height` - property; not function. Same with `$document.width`.

(also, it has duplicate `templateUrl`, but that shouldn't be the cause)

Other than that, it is defined correctly.

**EDIT:** another culprit could be the version of angular you are using. Only in 1.3+ you can use the element form `<ng-transclude>` - in earlier version you had to use an attribute form `<div ng-transclude>`

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2qOFSxjgbRpiK3htkfKR?p=preview)

Comment: <div ng-transclude> fixed the issue. I'm still on 1.2 for IE-8 support.

Answer (score 0):

ng-transclude needs something to transclude. Calling the directive without context means nothing.

Here is a fiddle for more information.

http://jsfiddle.net/ospatil/A969Z/158/light/

```
restrict: 'EA',
template: '<div class="span4 well clearfix"><div class="primary-block pull-right"></div><div class="secondary-block"></div><div class="transcluded" ng-transclude></div></div>',
replace: true,
transclude: true,
```

Comment: It should be transcluding everything in the directive in the view right? <div ng-controller="modalCtrl">
      <h1>Body</h1>
        <div class="" ng-click="close('yes')">Yes</div>
        <div class="" ng-click="close('no')">No</div>
    </div>

Comment: @byrdr, right - I'm not sure what lukegary meant when he said that there is nothing to transclude

Comment: https://thinkster.io/egghead/transclusion-basics
so, you need to put ng-transclude on the elements you want to have the view appended on, just putting in the tag ng-transclude means it is appending it to nothing, you need a start-tag

Comment: and so? The question clearly shows that there is content under `<modal>` element. I'm not sure what you mean by "it is appending it to nothing"?

Comment: there's a difference between being a property on a tag (the directive ng-transclude in this case) and being a child html node.

Comment: in other words, turn <ng-transclude></ng-transclude> to <div ng-transclude></div> or something

Comment: @byrdr, it works with the element form `<ng-transclude>` starting from version 1.3 - so make sure that this is the version you have. Otherwise, you should use it as an attribute: `<div ng-transclude>`

Comment: yeah, when he said just <ng-transclude> is showing up there's clearly a problem with the directive being picked up aka he's using older angular

Comment: @NewDev that was it. Thank you, I'm on 1.2 for IE-8 support. <div ng-transclude></div> solved it.

Comment: @byrdr in other words, turn <ng-transclude></ng-transclude> to <div ng-transclude></div> or something –  lukegary 25 mins ago   :-(